# Can client side mess with my API?

Tags: api, rest, soap

I have a website that revolves around transactions between two users. Each user needs to agree to the same terms. If I want an API so other websites can implement this into their own website, then I want to make sure that the other websites cannot mess with the process by including more fields in between or things that are irrelevant to my application. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you describe your workflow in more detail, including the technologies used? There's not enough information to answer right now, other than "no, that's not possible, with a correctly- and securely-designed site"

Comment: Agreed to Michael, it would be great if you can describe with an example maybe your scenario. Apart from that, in my opinion from the above text, you cannot force someone to implement your rules/protocol. But you can certainly check and certify which ones do.

Comment: On my website, user A can set up a new transaction with description and agreement to our terms of service. User B is emailed and can then agree to the same terms or edit the terms, which will go back to user A. I want users of other websites to setup transactions the same way, a description and agreement to our terms. My concern is that if one of the websites using my API will add in extra fields or terms of their own, and I want to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Do you mean using your service rather than API?

Comment: I have a service that a website wants to integrate. I want to make sure the website that does not change the way that service is offered to its clients.

Answer (score 1):

If I was to implement such a thing, I would allow other websites to use tokens/URLs/widgets that would link them to my website. So, for example, website X wants to use my service to agree user A and B on the same terms. Their page will have an embedded form/frame which would be generated from my website and user B will also receive an email with link to my website's page (or a page of website X with a form/frame generated from my server).
Consider how different sites use eBay to enable users to pay. You buy everything on the site but when you are paying, either you are taken to ebay page and come back after payment, or the website has a small form/frame that is directly linked to ebay.
But this is my solution, one way of doing it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, if you can share your email I can drop an email and we can move forward from there.

Comment: Sent you an email, you can delete the comment above with your email address in it to avoid spam.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your API is implemented. It takes considerably more work, thought, and engineering to build an API that can literally take any kind of data or to build an API that can take additional, named, key/value pairs as fields.

If you have implemented your API in this manner, then it's quite possible that users of this API could use it to extend functionality or build something slightly different by passing in additional data.

However, if your API is built to where specific values must be passed and these fields are *required*, then it becomes much more difficult for your API to be used in a manner that differs from what you originally intended.

For example, Google has many different API's for different purposes, and each API has a very specific number of required parameters that a developer must use in order to make a successful HTTP request. While the goal of these API's are to *allow* developers to extend functionality, they do allow access to only very specific pieces of data.

Lastly, you can use authentication to prevent unauthorized access to your API. The specific implementation details depend largely on the platform you're working with as well as how the API will be used. For instance, if users must login to use services provided by your API, then a form of OAuth may suffice. However, if other servers will consume your API, then the authorization will have to take place in the HTTP headers.

For more information on API best practices, see [7 Rules of Thumb When You Build an API](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/10/11/7-rules-of-thumb-when-you-build-an-api/), and a slideshow from a Google Engineer titled [How to Design a Good API and Why That Matters](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf).